# Google Cloud Storage - Download large Files dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 (2.2.1) to download a file the following code

```
private async Task<Stream> LoadStream(BlobFileStreamRequest request)
{
    var memStream = new MemoryStream();

    await LocalRetryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        var bucketName = request.StoreContext.BucketName;
        var fileName = FileName(request.StoreContext.RelativePath, request.FileName);

        await StorageClient.DownloadObjectAsync(bucketName, fileName, memStream);
        memStream.Position = 0;

    });

    return memStream;
}
```

Everything works fine up to file sizes of 2 GB and then Is tart seeing errors because ethe Memory Stream can't support sizes larger that 2 GB.

How can I download a file larger than 2 GB file and pass the stream it directly to my code?

Comment: Save it to a file instead?

Comment: try to install [cloud sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk) to your environment and try it to download.

Comment: If your app is built 32-bit the limit is 2 GB. For 64-bit builds this might help increase to 4 GB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element